# Why does my ID numbers change when I make a conversion to a sparse matrix?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

```
head(a)
```

Output is

```
1235 3216 3459 3669 7759 5438 
TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But when I run

```
Matrix(head(a), sparse = TRUE)
```

I get ...

```
[1,] |
[2,] .
[3,] |
[4,] |
[5,] .
[6,] .
```

WHY is the numbers changing???? Why is my output not like this?

```
1235 |
3216 .
3459 |
3669 |
7759 .
5438 .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the dimnames manually:

```
x <- c('1235'=TRUE,'3216'=FALSE,'3459'=TRUE,'3669'=TRUE,'7759'=FALSE,'5438'=FALSE)
Matrix(x, sparse=TRUE, dimnames=list(names(x)))
#6 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"
#      
#1235 |
#3216 .
#3459 |
#3669 |
#7759 .
#5438 .
```